# How to prevent event bubbling in Vuetify FAB buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, event-bubbling

How do I prevent event bubbling while pressing a [Vuetify's FAB buttons](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/floating-action-buttons/)?

Example: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/bGEXrjV?editors=1010. When pressing the FAB button the card's `@click` will also trigger.

Comment: You can try the `@click.stop` modifier or wrap the FAB button with `<div @click.stop>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@click.stop="doTrigger"`

Comment: Awesome thanks. For the record, here are all other VUE event modifiers: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers